# javascriptにおいてfetch()を使いたい

Tags: javascript, html

よろしくお願いいたします。

ブラウザ上からgooglehomeに話をさせるために
https://qiita.com/kyota/items/453047f236ca5488027c
を参考にし、下のようにindex.htmlを作成しました。

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>

        function fetch('./', {
            method: 'POST',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({msg:''})
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
            .then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
    </script>

    <p>
        <input type="button" value="おはよう" onclick="fetch()">
    </p>
    <form>
        <input type = "text" name="speak1"onclick="fetch()">
        <button>話す</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ボタンを押せばgooglehomeが"おはよう",または欄に入力された言葉を
話すようにしたいのですが、思ったようになりませんでした。

fetchの使い方を教えていただけましたら、幸いです。

Answer (score 2):

`function` は必要ありません。

#### 関数の利用法

関数の「宣言（定義）」と「呼び出し」を混同なさっているようです。今回はブラウザ環境に既に含まれている `fetch` という関数を使いたい、という事ですから行うべきは宣言ではなく、呼び出しです。`function` は付けずに、`fetch(引数...)` とします。

参考: [関数 - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)

#### エラーの確認法

一般に問題が生じた場合は、どういったエラーが出ているのか（あるいは出ていないのか）確認する必要があります。これに使うものとして、ブラウザによって呼び方は異なりますが、「開発ツール」の「コンソール」があります。今回の例では「構文エラーである」という意味のエラーを確認できるはずです。

参考: [Webコンソール - 開発ツール | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Tools/Web_Console)

Comment: コード見た感じ何らかを定義してonclickから呼びたいようなので「必要ありません」もまた微妙に違うのかな、とも(まあどっちにしろ根本的な話ですが)

Comment: コンソールでエラー確認できました。またgooglehomeが話すようになりました。ありがとうございます。